# puppet applly and deferred functions: Error: Unknown function 'mymodule::myupcase'

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm following [this puppet doc](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/write_a_puppet_function_to_store_secrets.html) to test Deferred functions, below I replicate the steps.

- start creating the required directory strucutre and running some [Puppet Develpment Kit (pdk)](https://www.puppet.com/downloads/puppet-development-kit) commands:

```bash
cd ~/dev/src/local/puppet_tests
pdk new module mymodule
cd mymodule
pdk new class mymodule
mkdir -p lib/puppet/functions/mymodule
```

- Next, you should paste the code below in your `manifest/init.pp` file:

```rb
class mymodule {
  $d = Deferred("mymodule::myupcase", ["mysecret"])

  notify { example :
    message => $d
  }
}

class { 'mymodule': }
```

- Next, create a file name `myupcase.rb` under the directory `lib/puppet/functions/mymodule` and paste the code below:

```rb
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'mymodule::myupcase') do
  dispatch :up do
    param 'String', :some_string
  end

  def up(some_string)
    Puppet::Pops::Types::PSensitiveType::Sensitive.new(some_string.upcase)
  end
end
```

- Now, you should run the `puppet apply manifest/init.pp`

```bash
~/dev/src/local/puppet_tests/mymodule main*
❯ puppet apply manifests/init.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for localhost.localdomain in environment production in 0.04 seconds
Error: Unknown function 'mymodule::myupcase'
```

Removing the following part of the code in the `init.pp` file, it works, but just because you remove the reference to the `$d` variable:

```rb
  notify { example :
    message => $d,
  }
```

What am I missing here ?

My S.O. is MacOX 13.4.1, puppet 8.1.0.
Installed both puppet-agent and pdk using brew:

```bash
brew install --cask puppetlabs/puppet/puppet-agent
brew install --cask puppetlabs/puppet/pdk
```

**EDITED:**

I have made an additional test, now using the `pdk new function` to create the function, but the error persists:

```bash
cd ~/dev/src/local/puppet_tests
pdk new module mymodule
cd mymodule
pdk new class mymodule
pdk new function myupcase --type=v4
```

It have created some additional directory named `spec/` with some additional files. The final `myupcase.rb` is:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-specifications/blob/master/language/func-api.md#the-4x-api
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:"mymodule::myupcase") do
  dispatch :myupcase do
    param 'String', :a
    return_type 'String'
  end
  # the function below is called by puppet and and must match
  # the name of the puppet function above. You can set your
  # required parameters below and puppet will enforce these
  # so change x to suit your needs although only one parameter is required
  # as defined in the dispatch method.
  def myupcase(x)
    x.upcase
  end

  # you can define other helper methods in this code block as well
end
```

The `init.pp` file remains the same.

Comment: The question is missing the function definition and invocation. We cannot assist without either.

Comment: I hope to have added all the required information now :)

Comment: If you are using `pdk` then why not use the `new function` subcommand? Since this appears to be an autoloading issue, then that may fix this issue for you.

Comment: I have recreated everything, now using pdk. For the function i used the command `pdk new function myupcase --type=v4`. The only thing I have changed manually is the `init.pp` file to use the same code sample from the docs. Still, getting a `Error: Unknown function 'mymodule::myupcase'`. I will update the question with this additional test.

Comment: `pdk test unit`?

Comment: You appear to have followed the documentation faithfully, but the `puppet apply` step there looks suspect to me.  Aside from `puppet apply` being disfavored for some time, I would expect that in order for it to locate your function, the directory `~/dev/src/local/puppet_tests` would need to be in its modulepath.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you nailed it. Thank you very much. You can post your comment as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function itself looks fine, and you appear to have placed it properly in your module.  **That `puppet apply` does not find it likely arises from your module not being in its module path** (and you have already confirmed this). Similar errors would arise if the main class tried to use any other contents of the module: other classes, defined types, module data, *etc*.

Overall, the last step of the documentation, wherein you test the function by `apply`ing `manifests/init.pp` seems very ill advised, and when it does work to test the function, that's only because the module's `init.pp` contains `class { 'mymodule': }` at top scope, which is a whole other level of bad.

This is what you should do instead:

- remove the class declaration `class { 'mymodule': }` from your module's `init.pp`.  It simply should not be there.
- ensure that the parent directory (`~/dev/src/local/puppet_tests`) of your module directory is in Puppet's modulepath.
- if you want to test with `puppet apply` then create a separate manifest for that, anywhere:

  **test.pp**

  ```
  include mymodule
  ```

  Note: as a general rule, prefer include-like class declarations such as that over resource-like ones such as we removed from `init.pp`.

  Use the the command `/path/to/puppet apply path/to/test.pp` to run the test.